# Como pasar ByteArray desde Activity a Fragment (Tabbed Activity) actulizando continuamente

Tags: android-fragment, kotlin, activity, adapter

Estoy intentado escribir los valores conseguidos desde un activity guardandolos en un ByteArray para posteriormente procesarlos y escribirlos en los label de un fragment.

El ByteArray recoge los datos desde el notificador bluetooth por lo que esta cambiando su contenido constantemente.

Os muestro mi codigo para ver si podeis ayudarme.

Esta función recoge el array con los datos, es llamada cada vez que el notificador me envia un ByteArray con los datos:

```
fun rellenarfases(arrayDatos: ByteArray) {

    val sectionsPagerAdapter = SectionsPagerAdapter(this, supportFragmentManager)


    if (arrayDatos[0] == 0.toByte()) {
        //guardamos el valor en un array para mostrar
        arrayValores1 = arrayDatos
        //arrayValores1 = byteArrayOf(1.toByte(),2.toByte(),3.toByte())

        ///Envia el array al sectionPagerAdapter para luego mandarlo a su fragment correspondiente
        sectionsPagerAdapter.setArray(arrayValores1)

        sectionsPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()}
```

Este seria el codigo del SectionPagerAdapter, en esta parte recibo el array y segun la primera posición determino hacia que fragment tengo que mandar el ByteArray. Mediante la funcion setArray() recojo el contenido del valor dado por el activity:

```
class SectionsPagerAdapter(private val context: Context, fm: FragmentManager) : FragmentPagerAdapter(fm) {


//Nombre de las pestañas
private val TAB_TITLES = arrayOf(
    "l1",
    "l2",
    "l3",
    "l4"
)


var arrayValores = byteArrayOf(0.toByte(),0.toByte(),0.toByte(),0.toByte(),0.toByte(),0.toByte(),0.toByte(),0.toByte(),
    0.toByte(),0.toByte(),0.toByte(),0.toByte(),0.toByte(),0.toByte(),0.toByte(),0.toByte(),0.toByte(),0.toByte(),0.toByte(),
    0.toByte(),0.toByte(),0.toByte(),0.toByte(),0.toByte(),0.toByte(),0.toByte(),0.toByte(),0.toByte(),0.toByte(),0.toByte(),
    0.toByte(),0.toByte(),0.toByte(),0.toByte(),0.toByte(),0.toByte())

override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment {
    // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
    // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).
    if ( verArrayVacio(arrayValores) == true) {
        print ( "El array esta vacio")
    } else {
        if (position == 0) {
            if (arrayValores[0] == 0.toByte()) {
                //return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance2(byteArrayOf(1.toByte(),2.toByte(),3.toByte()))
                return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance2(arrayValores)
            }
        }
        if (position == 1) {
            //return PlaceholderFragment2.newInstance(position + 1)
            if (arrayValores[0] == 1.toByte()) {
                //return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance2(byteArrayOf(1.toByte(),2.toByte(),3.toByte()))
                return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance2(arrayValores)
            }
        }
        if (position == 2) {
            //return PlaceholderFragment3.newInstance(position + 1)
            if (arrayValores[0] == 2.toByte()) {
                //return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance2(byteArrayOf(1.toByte(),2.toByte(),3.toByte()))
                return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance2(arrayValores)
            }
        }
        if (position == 3) {
            //return PlaceholderFragment4.newInstance(position + 1)
            if (arrayValores[0] == 3.toByte()) {
                //return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance2(byteArrayOf(1.toByte(),2.toByte(),3.toByte()))
                return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance2(arrayValores)
            }
        }
    }
    return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance2(arrayValores)
}

//manda el valor del array
fun getArray(): ByteArray {
    return arrayValores
}

//Recoge el valor del array desde otro activity
fun setArray(array:ByteArray) {
    this.arrayValores = array
    print(arrayValores)
    getItem(arrayValores[0].toInt())
}

fun verArrayVacio(array: ByteArray) : Boolean {
    if (array.contentEquals(byteArrayOf(0.toByte(),0.toByte(),0.toByte(),0.toByte(),0.toByte(),0.toByte(),0.toByte(),0.toByte(),
            0.toByte(),0.toByte(),0.toByte(),0.toByte(),0.toByte(),0.toByte(),0.toByte(),0.toByte(),0.toByte(),0.toByte(),0.toByte(),
            0.toByte(),0.toByte(),0.toByte(),0.toByte(),0.toByte(),0.toByte(),0.toByte(),0.toByte(),0.toByte(),0.toByte(),0.toByte(),
            0.toByte(),0.toByte(),0.toByte(),0.toByte(),0.toByte(),0.toByte())) == true) {
        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }
}

override fun getPageTitle(position: Int): CharSequence? {
    return context.resources.getString(TAB_TITLES[position])
}

//Numero de pestañas
override fun getCount(): Int {
    // Show 4 total pages.
    return 4
}
```

}

Este es mi fragment, aqui mediante el bundle recibo el ByteArray e intento pintar el contenido en los TextView del fragment pero no consigo que pinte nada, y lo que me gustaria es pintar y que cada vez que el contenido del ByteArray cambie, se vuelva a mandar todo de nuevo y cambie el resultado de los TextView:

```
class PlaceholderFragment : Fragment() {

private lateinit var pageViewModel: PageViewModel


override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    pageViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(PageViewModel::class.java).apply {
        setIndex(arguments?.getInt(KEY_REG_TEXT) ?: 1)

    }
}



override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    val root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_informes, container, false)


    //recoge el valor del array pasado por el sectionPagerAdapter a traves del Bundle
    val message = arguments!!.getByteArray(KEY_REG_TEXT)

    val instTension: TextView = root.findViewById(R.id.instTension)
    val maxTension: TextView = root.findViewById(R.id.maxTension)
    val minTension: TextView = root.findViewById(R.id.minTension)
    val instCorriente: TextView = root.findViewById(R.id.instCorriente)
    val maxCorriente: TextView = root.findViewById(R.id.maxCorriente)
    val minCorriente: TextView = root.findViewById(R.id.minCorriente)
    val instActiva: TextView = root.findViewById(R.id.instActiva)
    val maxActiva: TextView = root.findViewById(R.id.maxActiva)
    val minActiva: TextView = root.findViewById(R.id.minActiva)
    val instInductiva: TextView = root.findViewById(R.id.instInductiva)
    val maxInductiva: TextView = root.findViewById(R.id.maxInductiva)
    val minInductiva: TextView = root.findViewById(R.id.minInductiva)
    val instCapacitiva: TextView = root.findViewById(R.id.instCapacitiva)
    val maxCapacitiva: TextView = root.findViewById(R.id.maxCapacitiva)
    val minCapacitiva: TextView = root.findViewById(R.id.minCapacitiva)
    val instAparente: TextView = root.findViewById(R.id.instAparente)
    val maxAparente: TextView = root.findViewById(R.id.maxAparente)
    val minAparente: TextView = root.findViewById(R.id.minAparente)
    val instFactor: TextView = root.findViewById(R.id.instFactor)
    val maxFactor: TextView = root.findViewById(R.id.maxFactor)
    val minFactor: TextView = root.findViewById(R.id.minFactor)
    val instCoseno: TextView = root.findViewById(R.id.instCoseno)
    val maxCoseno: TextView = root.findViewById(R.id.maxCoseno)
    val minCoseno: TextView = root.findViewById(R.id.minCoseno)


    if (message[1] == 0.toByte()) {

        instTension.text = convertirValores(message[2],message[3],message[4],message[5])
        var test = convertirValores(message[2],message[3],message[4],message[5])
        Log.e("VALORESI",test)
        instCorriente.text = convertirValores(message[6],message[7],message[8],message[9])
        instActiva.text = convertirValores(message[10],message[11],message[12],message[13])
        instInductiva.text = convertirValores(message[14],message[15],message[16],message[17])
        instCapacitiva.text = convertirValores(message[18],message[19],message[20],message[21])
        instAparente.text = convertirValores(message[22],message[23],message[24],message[25])
        instFactor.text = convertirValores(message[26],message[27],message[28],message[29])
        instCoseno.text = convertirValores(message[30],message[31],message[32],message[33])

    }

    if (message[1] == 1.toByte()) {

        maxTension.text = convertirValores(message[2],message[3],message[4],message[5])
        var test = convertirValores(message[2],message[3],message[4],message[5])
        Log.e("VALORESI",test)
        maxCorriente.text = convertirValores(message[6],message[7],message[8],message[9])
        maxActiva.text = convertirValores(message[10],message[11],message[12],message[13])
        maxInductiva.text = convertirValores(message[14],message[15],message[16],message[17])
        maxCapacitiva.text = convertirValores(message[18],message[19],message[20],message[21])
        maxAparente.text = convertirValores(message[22],message[23],message[24],message[25])
        maxFactor.text = convertirValores(message[26],message[27],message[28],message[29])
        maxCoseno.text = convertirValores(message[30],message[31],message[32],message[33])

    }

    if (message[1] == 2.toByte()) {

        minTension.text = convertirValores(message[2],message[3],message[4],message[5])
        var test = convertirValores(message[2],message[3],message[4],message[5])
        Log.e("VALORESI",test)
        minCorriente.text = convertirValores(message[6],message[7],message[8],message[9])
        minActiva.text = convertirValores(message[10],message[11],message[12],message[13])
        minInductiva.text = convertirValores(message[14],message[15],message[16],message[17])
        minCapacitiva.text = convertirValores(message[18],message[19],message[20],message[21])
        minAparente.text = convertirValores(message[22],message[23],message[24],message[25])
        minFactor.text = convertirValores(message[26],message[27],message[28],message[29])
        minCoseno.text = convertirValores(message[30],message[31],message[32],message[33])

    }

    return root
}

fun convertirValores(byte1 : Byte, byte2: Byte, byte3: Byte,byte4: Byte) : String{

    var byteArray = byteArrayOf(byte1,byte2,byte3,byte4)

    val convertirString = String(byteArray, StandardCharsets.UTF_8).replace(0.toChar().toString(), "")

    return convertirString
}

companion object {
    /**
     * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
     * fragment.
     */


    //private const val ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number"

    /**
     * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
     * number.
     */
    @JvmStatic
    var  KEY_REG_TEXT = "text"



    fun newInstance2(array: ByteArray): PlaceholderFragment {
        val frag = PlaceholderFragment()

        var args: Bundle? = Bundle()
        frag.getArguments()
        if (args == null)
            args = Bundle()

        args.putByteArray(KEY_REG_TEXT, array)

        frag.setArguments(args)

        return frag
    }


}
```

Tambien entra en juego (aunque no se para que sirve) un ViewModel el cual os dejo el codigo por si fuera necesario:

```
class PageViewModel : ViewModel() {


private val _index = MutableLiveData<Int>()


    var instTension : LiveData<String> = Transformations.map(_index) {
        "$it"
    }
    var maxTension: LiveData<String> = Transformations.map(_index) {
        "$it"
    }
    var minTension: LiveData<String> = Transformations.map(_index) {
        "$it"
    }
    var instCorriente: LiveData<String> = Transformations.map(_index) {
        "$it"
    }
    var maxCorriente: LiveData<String> = Transformations.map(_index) {
        "$it"
    }
    var minCorriente: LiveData<String> = Transformations.map(_index) {
        "$it"
    }
    var instActiva: LiveData<String> = Transformations.map(_index) {
        "$it"
    }
    var maxActiva: LiveData<String> = Transformations.map(_index) {
        "$it"
    }
    var minActiva: LiveData<String> = Transformations.map(_index) {
        "$it"
    }

    var instInductiva: LiveData<String> = Transformations.map(_index) {
        "$it"
    }

    var maxInductiva: LiveData<String> = Transformations.map(_index) {
        "$it"
    }
    var minInductiva: LiveData<String> = Transformations.map(_index) {
        "$it"
    }

    var instCapacitiva: LiveData<String> = Transformations.map(_index) {
        "$it"
    }
    var maxCapacitiva: LiveData<String> = Transformations.map(_index) {
        "$it"
    }
    var minCapacitiva: LiveData<String> = Transformations.map(_index) {
        "$it"
    }
    var instAparente: LiveData<String> = Transformations.map(_index) {
        "$it"
    }
    var maxAparente: LiveData<String> = Transformations.map(_index) {
        "$it"
    }
    var minAparente: LiveData<String> = Transformations.map(_index) {
        "$it"
    }
    var instFactor: LiveData<String> = Transformations.map(_index) {
        "$it"
    }
    var maxFactor: LiveData<String> = Transformations.map(_index) {
        "$it"
    }
    var minFactor: LiveData<String> = Transformations.map(_index) {
        "$it"
    }
    var instCoseno: LiveData<String> = Transformations.map(_index) {
        "$it"
    }
    var minCoseno: LiveData<String> = Transformations.map(_index) {
        "$it"
    }
    var maxCoseno: LiveData<String> = Transformations.map(_index) {
        "$it"
    }




fun setIndex(index: Int) {
    _index.value = index
}
```

Muchisimas gracias de antemano y espero que podais ayudarme.

Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

Sigo intentanto solucionar el problema... lo que si he podido comprobar es que si en vez de mandar el ByteArray desde la función que recibe el ByteArray del notificador Bluetooth lo envio de forma "manual" desde el onCreate del Activity si que lo pinta, lo que ocurre es que necesito que se envie el ByteArray que me devuelve el notificador contantemente y me modifique la vista del fragment cada vez que el notificador del activity me devuelve un valor distinto.

Por favor ayudarme.

Un saludo.